# Android Soft-Key-Buttons hide view's content

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, softkeys

I'm having troubles with layouts being too large on Devices with Soft-Key-Buttons on Android:

Summing up, my question is why a layout, which is configured as ***"match_parent"*** has its View-bounds extended to the "real" bottom window bound, instead of just above the Soft-Key-Buttons?

Now to my specific problem:

While displaying a RelativeLayout (in a Fragment, if thats necessary to know) with a View ***layout_alignParentBottom="true"*** on any Device with Soft-Key-Buttons, the View is displayed "behind" the Soft-Key-Buttons.

[Image of the View on a Device without Soft-Key-Buttons (as it should be)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6luE5.png)

[Image of the View on a Device with Soft-Key-Buttons (the Button is "hiding" behind the Soft-Keys)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LluHC.png)

The RelativeLayout looks like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg2">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/settings_container_margin_top"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- Some views -->

    </LinearLayout>

    <at.eventdrivers.android.ui.MenuButton
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        custom:btnText="@string/..." />

</RelativeLayout>
```

As I'm quite new to Android Development and also have not done anything before with Fragments, the error could also be in the fragment-management, so I'm going to post this too:

The Activity, in which the fragment is shown, is configured in the AndroidManifest:

```
<activity
    android:name=".slidingmenu.SlidingHomeActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:logo="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

The used FrameLayouts all have layout_width and layout_height set to match_parent.

Right now I'm using kind of a workaround with programmatically checking if the device is showing Soft-Key-Buttons, and if yes, setting the margin of this Button to a higher value:

```
public static boolean hasSoftKeys(Context c) {
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 10 || (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14 &&
            ViewConfiguration.get(c).hasPermanentMenuKey())) {
        //menu key is present
        return false;
    } else {
        //No menu key
        return true;
    }
}
```

The problem there is, that the Soft-Key-Buttons have a different height on different devices, so I would have to check the height of the Soft-Key-Buttons too (which is possible and already answered on StackOverflow).

I'm stuck at this problem for a few weeks now and would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can imagine three different scenarios:

1. (Unlikely)You do something with `LayoutParams` Flags of your `Window`(like `getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);`) and/or Theme's styles
2. (Unlikely. It was my initial though, but `layout_alignParentBottom="true"` should handle it for you)You don't have enough space on the screen. Can you wrap your `RelativeLayout` into a [`ScrollView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html)(it'd require you to change `RelativeLayout`'s height to `wrap_content`) and see the result? (If you set `match_parent` to the `RelativeLayout` it does not mean it'd fit all content into the screen sizes. Content can easily get out of the screen, like on the screenshot you provided. But again, `layout_alignParentBottom="true"` handles it.
3. (Most likely) You have some margins/paddings in the `Activity`(especially, something like `android:layout_marginBottom="-XXdp"`), which hosts `Fragment`. So fragment is rendering correctly, but the Activity moves it below the screen.

To speak more precisely, it'd be nice to have `@style/AppBaseTheme` here, Activity's layout and if you do something suspicious with `getWindow()` - this piece of code.

Let me know, if it helps or not!

Comment: I've checked all your 3 scenarios and the only time I'm using **getWindow()** in a way, it could interfere with the fragment/activity, is in the jfeinstein10's [SlidingMenu-Library](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu).
There it is used if the mode SLIDING_WINDOW is selected. This probably changes some parameters so the soft-keys are "hiding" some content (or i'm just doing it wrong).
**To sum up**, changing the Sliding-Menu's mode to **SLIDING_CONTENT** solves my problem.
So thank you for your quick and very detailed answer!

Comment: @FlorianMötz I have same issue with sliding menu but i have changed mode to SLIDNG_CONTENT doest not solve my issue can you please help me

Comment: @PriyankaChauhan Did u solve urs problem , i have stucked in the same problem yet..Please help me on it

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha I had solved issue by adding some code in SlidingMenu.java

Comment: @PriyankaChauhan CAn u plz share it

Comment: check this link https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/issues/680 and find anwer form "Den-Rimus"

Comment: @PriyankaChauhan    It resolve the issue but it is occurring the white gap on other devices.New issue generated :P

Comment: public boolean isNavigationBarAvailable() {

        boolean hasBackKey = KeyCharacterMap.deviceHasKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK);
        boolean hasHomeKey = KeyCharacterMap.deviceHasKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME);

        return (!(hasBackKey && hasHomeKey));
    } add this function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153919/discussion-between-priyankachauhan-and-ravindra-kushwaha).

Answer (score 4):

This one worked for me, just add it to your v21/styles.xml

```
<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">false</item>
```

Comment: I have researched this problem a lot but solved only with your solution, thank you very much