# Floating Action Button appears too low

Tags: android, xml

I have made a tabbed activity and i want to put a FAB to the bottom right of a fragment which appears when i press the corresponding tab.My problem is that the FAB appears too low as the following screenshot shows.

My activity_main.xml is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        app:title="@string/app_name">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/tabItem"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/tab_text_1" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/tabItem2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/tab_text_2" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/tabItem3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/tab_text_3" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

and the fragment_layout.xml

```
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/search_fragment_layout"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/testLabel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:text="TextView" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:useCompatPadding="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp" />
```

and here is the screenshot

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbQea.png

I tried to set bottom padding of coordinator layout in fragment_layout.xml and it kinda worked but i dont think that is a good solution so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Look into this [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34577595/android-soft-key-buttons-hide-views-content).

Answer (score 0):

Use below code and tell me if it helped you or not.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
 android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 tools:context="www.immacbytes.com.Activities.home"> 

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/white"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"
    app:elevation="6dp">
</android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton>
```